# SQL Join failing with CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Im trying to join two tables but cannot seem to figure out how to resolve this error:
This is the code generated from CodeIgniter:

```
SELECT `proc`.* FROM (`deliverycheck_proc_entries` proc) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `deliverycheck_proc_entries` 
ON `proc`.`raw_entry_id` = `deliverycheck_raw_entries`.`id` 
WHERE `proc`.`status` > '1' 
ORDER BY `id` asc LIMIT 10
```

My error:

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'deliverycheck_raw_entries.id' in 'on clause'
```

I need all the columns from `deliverycheck_proc_entries` and specific from `deliverycheck_raw-entries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `deliverycheck_proc_entries`
```

to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `deliverycheck_raw_entries`
```

### Edit

```
SELECT proc.*, raw.* 
FROM deliverycheck_proc_entries `proc`
LEFT OUTER JOIN deliverycheck_raw_entries raw
ON proc.raw_entry_id = raw.id 
WHERE proc.status > '1' 
ORDER BY proc.id ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What does it require to include columns from `deliverycheck_raw_entries` along in my result array?

Comment: change `SELECT proc.* FROM ...` to `SELECT * FROM ...` or `SELECT proc.*, deliverycheck_raw_entries.*  FROM ...`

Comment: I get `Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous` i assume it may be because i have an `id`  column in both tables?

Comment: then name the column you want to order by. Either `deliverycheck_raw_entries.id` or `deliverycheck_proc_entries.id`

Comment: That succeeded. But all the columns in the array from `deliverycheck_raw_entries` are empty for some reason.

Comment: Hmm. Then the `ON` condition did not work. Is `proc.raw_entry_id` really `raw.id`? Can you show some example data?

Comment: I use it many other situations without any problems. All `raw_entry_id` point to a existing `raw.id`. For example `[raw_entry_id] => 802` does indeed exist in the `raw` table.

Comment: So i have cut off columns to keep it tidy: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f251c and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99af9 as i mentioned earlier this is a running system which is working with both tables.

Comment: Its very odd. I even tried to use your custom query, still no columns with data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19655/discussion-between-juergen-d-and-javacake)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a typo but you have joined `deliverycheck_proc_entries` with itself instead of `deliverycheck_raw_entries`.